# Array mediante i2C

Tags: array, c

¿Sería posible que un dato que me arroja un sensor (el dato arrojado es de tipo `unsigned char`) mediante el comando `i2c_read()`, `dato=10101010`, sea guardado en un `array` como `datoarray[8]={1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0}` en vez de como tipo `unsigned char`?

Programo en C.

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo que antes de nada pases por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).Pulsa en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/220673/edit) y añade información de lo que pretendes y sobre todo lo que has intentado y qué problemas concretos has tenido. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para más información en cómo mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Mira esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564813/how-to-convert-integer-to-character-array-using-c y hazle caso al compañero meegle84, aprender a formular bien las preguntas.